# How to inline ignore format in Visual Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, formatting

Which formatter does Visual Code use? I read somewhere it uses `jsbeautifier` so I tried adding a compatible ignore comment to my `.ejs` template, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 8):

As far as I know, there is no way to do this without an extension.

However, you have full control of the formatting if you use [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HookyQR.beautify). It also uses js-beautify, but it adds configuration.

As specified in the js-beautify [docs](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify), the "preserve" directive only works in javascript sections. I have tested this in the script tag of an `ejs` file and formatting the document does NOT change the indentation of the `console.log` statement. This worked without changing any settings at all, actually. I simply installed the extension, saved this file as `index.ejs` and observed that vscode had the language mode set to `html`.

My test page

```
// These comments DON'T work because they aren't in a javascript section of the code
/* beautify preserve:start */
<h1><%= title %></h1>
/* beautify preserve:end */
<ul>
</ul>
<script>
    function log() {
        // Without the beautify comments, format document will move console.log 
        // to align with this
        /* beautify preserve:start */
                console.log('hello');
        /* beautify preserve:end */
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Tried this approach. I can tell the extension is now formatting the file (VC detects `*.ejs` as HTML so I configured `beautify` to respect `*.html`), but the `ignore/preserve` comments seem to be ignored. I tried to put them after the `script` tag, despite less ideal and that doesn't work either. I found out I can stop the formatter by assigning `{"beautify.ignore": "index.ejs"}` to my `.vscode/settings.json`. Obviously less than ideal, since you must have the `beautify` extension installed. It seems odd I can't override VC `settings.json` with an inline comment.

Comment: I've updated my answer with more information and an example of the comments working for me.

I agree that this should work without an extension. You can create an issue on [github](https://www.github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new) to request this feature.

Comment: Sweet, I'll give it another shot.

Comment: Great, please accept the answer to let me know that it worked, or let me know what didn't work, preferably with a code sample or something