# How to avoid VSCode format a part of the code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am looking for a way to make sure VSCode is not formatting a part of my code. (using Javascript)

Is there a tag that I could use that I could put around a part of my code and VSCode will ignore it and will not format it?

```
/* CODE FORMAT OFF */
const grp = func()
    .configure()
        .initialState()
            .on()
    .global()
        .on()
    .getC()
/* CODE FORMAT ON */
```

I have Prettier add-on installed, but not sure it is enabled.

Comment: What is `ts-ignore` from, and where could we read about what it does, in order to answer? What type of code are you writing? as I found [one way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46214935/how-to-inline-ignore-format-in-visual-code) that apparently only wors for JavaScript.

Comment: @underscore_d, forget about ts-ignore, that was just an example that can be used to ignore warning, for example. The language use is javascript.